# How scope of variable defined/flows in SQL statements compared to LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, c#-3.0

Here in this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/scobleizer/Anders-Hejlsberg-LINQ/) at 11th minute, while explaining about strange structure (compared to SQL) of LINQ query, [Anders Hejlsberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg) says that "Scope of variables in SQL flows backward in SQL", What does he mean by that? I'm totally confused... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this simple SQL statement:-

```
 SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM People
```

Lexically we establish what fields we want (FirstName, LastName) from **whatever** before we define where we are getting them from (People).  Whereas:-

```
var query = from People select new {FirstName, LastName}
```

Lexically we establish from where we are getting data (People) before we define which specific bits of that data we want (FirstName, LastName).  The SQL approach is backward.

Comment: Nah, in practice we do SELECT * FROM People and then work out which columns we need :)